Installing nvChad on Ubuntu
Following instructions here:
https://nvchad.com/docs/quickstart/install/
They are pretty simple. I ran
sudo git clone https://github.com/NvChad/starter ~/.config/nvim && sudo nvim-linux64/bin/nvim

which succeeded.
Then I run :MasonInstallAll in nvim, but I am getting:
E492: Not an editor command: MasonInstallAll

Instructions say

Run :MasonInstallAll command after lazy.nvim finishes downloading plugins.

Maybe it didn't finish dowloading? How do I know? Or is the problem elsewhere?

Your problem is related to the tilde (~) shell expansion.
You are running:
sudo git clone https://github.com/NvChad/starter ~/.config/nvim && sudo nvim-linux64/bin/nvim

You are using sudo for both commands (why run all this as root?), however, the tilde expansion happens for the current user running the command. Then you are running nvim as root, but root probably doesn't have any NvChad nvim config in /root/.config/nvim.
For example, if you are running these commands as "myuser1", the tilde expansion results in the following path /home/myuser1/.config/nvim.
There are many ways to solve your problem (listing only very simple ones).

Don't use shell expansion:

sudo git clone https://github.com/NvChad/starter /root/.config/nvim && sudo nvim-linux64/bin/nvim


Switch to root, then run the commands without sudo (you will have to adjust the path to nvim-linux64/bin/nvim or move it into root's home directory)

sudo su -
git clone https://github.com/NvChad/starter ~/.config/nvim && nvim-linux64/bin/nvim


Thank you for your comment! I have tried replacing ~ with explicit path to my homedir and the problem remained :-(
I have also verified that it indeed cloned the repo where it should.
Maybe I could check explicit file where the command is supposed to be defined? I don't know where thouhg.
Thanks again for your help!

Please provide more details as to what you are trying to do.
Are you trying to install NvChad config for the root user or your non-root user?
You mentioned having changed the path explicitly to your home dir, which sounds like you do NOT want to run as root. If that is the case, then you should not use sudo and simply run nvim-linux64/bin/nvim.
When nvim starts up, it will look for ~/.config/nvim, if you run nvim with sudo it will therefore look in /root/.config/nvim whereas if you run without sudo, it will look in /home/user/.config/nvim ("user" here is obviously an example)
